# cargar un archivo con ajax en mvc

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

Muy buenos a todos, quería saber si me podían ayuda con un problema, estoy tratando de cargar un archivo desde Ajax para enviar a un controlador. El error que tengo es no me deja cargar en Ajax archivos grandes, me envía al error de Ajax. El problema se produce haciéndolo tipo submit o sea antes de presionar el botón para enviar el controlador, el código es el siguiente de Ajax:

```
function ActualizarArrayAdjuntos(_archivo) {
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        async: false,
        url: "@Url.Action("ActualizarArrayAdjuntos")",
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify({ archivo: _archivo, tipoMantenimiento: _tipoMantenimiento }),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        error: function (response) {
            MsgInformacion(EtiquetasMensaje.Fallo, EtiquetasMensaje.OperacionError);
        },
        success: function (response) {
            if (response == -1) {
                MsgInformacion(EtiquetasMensaje.Fallo, "Ocurrio un error a la hora de adjuntar el archivo.");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Cuando intento adjuntar el archivo muestra el mensaje                     MsgInformacion(EtiquetasMensaje.Fallo, EtiquetasMensaje.OperacionError), del error, esto solo sucede con archivos grandes.

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Necesitas aumentar el tamaño máximo permitido en el request del server, de la misma manera, el execution timeout usando la sección `<httpRuntime>` en tu web.config:

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime 
        maxRequestLength="tamaño en kbytes"
        executionTimeout="segundos"
    />
...        
</system.web>
```

Y en caso estás haciendo un deploy en IIS 7.0+ quizás necesites aumentar el tamaño máximo permitido en el request usando `<requestLimits>` dentro de la sección `<system.webServer>`:

```
<system.webServer>
    <security>
        <requestFiltering>
            <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="tamaño en bytes" />
        </requestFiltering>
    </security>

    ...
</system.webServer>
```

Respuesta original en SOen: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9281987/3613462

Answer (score 0):

aumenta el tamaño en tu app.config

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="500" maxRequestLength="29296" />   </system.web>
```